# Using MariaDB on server

Tags: distribution, gpl-2

MariaDB server is [GPLv2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/licensing-faq/).
I plan to use it on a server, unmodified, for let's say an online shop.
The users would have a GUI and through this GUI they would add products to a cart.

Would this be considered distribution (and trigger the GPLv2 license conditions) or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you never distribute the code to anyone else and you never change anything GPLv2 is not triggered by your usage.

Comment: So the trigger is the source code distribution and not interaction with the user.

Comment: But can we assume in this way that any GPLv2 library that is run on a server will never trigger the license obligations ? (of course with the user not having direct access to the source code)

Comment: Right, the simple usage - no matter about the amount of users - is not part of GPLv2. Part instead is distribution of source-code, this is possible in combination with own code or code from other sources. Latter case is usually done by keeping the licenses of main- and each sub-package but there never exists a  (cover-all) license for combined licenses.